# git で指定ファイルのプロジェクトルートからの相対パスを取得したい

Tags: git, shellscript

エディタで git 管理されているファイルを見ているとき、このファイルが git のルートディレクトリからの相対パスが、一体どうなっているのか気になりました。

指定されたパスのファイルが、 git のルートからの相対パスがどうなっているかを取得するコマンドなどはありますでしょうか。これができると、たとえば github 上の該当ページを open する、といったような、もろもろのスクリプト作成が可能だろうと思い、質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

少し、調べたらでてきたので自己回答します。

```
git ls-files --full-name committed-file
```

とやると、`committed-file` というファイルの、 git ルートからの相対パスが取得できました。